# collatz problem with function that checks is number even or odd

Tags: python, collatz

I'm noob with programing and python.
I have problem with making collatz program with function that checks if number is even or odd.
Without function my code is working fine
Second code is with function(I have infinite loop)- what I'm doing wrong?

```
number = 44   
while number != 1:    
    if number%2 == 0:        
        number = number//2
        print(number)
    else:
        number = 3*number+1
        print(number)
```

```
number = 44
def collatz(number):    
    if number%2 == 0:        
        number = number//2
        return number  
    else:
        number = 3*number+1
        return number    
while number != 1:    
    print(collatz(number))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second snippet of code can be rearranged like this:

```py
def collatz(number):    
    if number%2 == 0:        
        number = number//2
        return number  
    else:
        number = 3*number+1
        return number    


number = 44
while number != 1:    
    print(collatz(number))
```

Now you might be able to see that `number` in the lower half of the code is isolated from `def collatz()`.

What happens is that `number` starts off having `44` and gets passed into the `collatz()` function, which returns a new number which you `print()`, but otherwise gets thrown away and has nothing to do with `number`, which retains its value `44` since it is not reassigned anywhere.

Also note that `def name():` forms a new scope which supercedes other scopes. Also your definition is: `def collatz(number):` which means that `number` is a parameter of the function and definitely local to the function.